# Can we have better reasons for dismissing topic requests?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Right now, clicking "dismiss" on a documentation request shows these three options:

- already exists
- is not necessary
- is not a real request

The first one is clear and useful, it's basically a "duplicate" flag. The third one seems to be similar to the NARQ flag, I assume it is intended for people writing gibberish or random stuff instead of a request. Which would mean that "not neccessary" is supposed to cover all other possible issues with a documentation request. But most of the problematic requests I see are too broad (e.g. ["Microservices using python"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topic-requests/2429)), which doesn't seem to be adequately represented by "not neccessary". As such, I request that the options for dismissal are either

- (1) extended to cover further cases, such as too broad; or
- (2) changed so that "not neccessary" is replaced with a text that expresses that the topic isn't fit for SO documentation, something like "out of scope for SO docs"

Furhtermore, the options currently do not have any help text to explain their intended use. This should be added regardless of which option is chosen.

Comment: To add to this, I would literally love whoever gives us an option like "should be a request for an example on an existing topic", which would then allow you to search (autocomplete-style) for a topic, choose it, and auto-create a request for improvement (specifically for a new example) by copying the content of the topic request (perhaps also with the option to edit that content for clarification, as needed)...seriously, 95% of the topic request dismissals I've done have been for that exact reason :)

Comment: I agree that the dismissal options should be extended to include "too broad," or "outside the scope." [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topic-requests/4679) where it is a real request that also shouldn't be called unnecessary, yet it's expected to cram a book's worth of content onto a page.

Comment: Agreed, here is another example of this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topic-requests/4735#comments